# Restrict the number of cores available to an Akka application

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I am trying to run some experiments to study the scaling properties of an Akka application that I have written.  As a baseline I would like to force the application to run using only a single thread on a single core.

I am currently running the simulation on my quad-core laptop with the following in my `application.conf` file...

```
akka {
    actor {
        default-dispatcher {

            fork-join-executor {

                parallelism-min = 1

                parallelism-factor = 0.25

                parallelism-max = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct best way to force my application to run as a single threaded application on one core?  The idea is that once I have this baseline, I will then increase the number of available cores (and threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work. I would just add that the declaration of `parallelism-max` would be already enough in your case. The `parallelism-factor` is just used in the following formula: `available processors * factor`. Akka first uses the formula to determine the number of threads that should be used. Next it makes sure you are within the min & max. So a number below 1 for the factor makes no sense. I think the best thing for you should be the following:

```
akka {
    actor {
        default-dispatcher {

            fork-join-executor {
                parallelism-max = X // set it to the number of cores you want to allow
                parallelism-factor = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html).

Comment: Thanks. My thinking on setting parallelism-factor < 1 was that by specifying `parallelism-factor=0.25` I was telling Akka that I wanted `0.25 * 4 = 1` thread.

Comment: Is there any easy way to tell that Akka has picked up and is using the new configuration?  When I run my application it is pretty clear from my Activity Monitor that the app is still using all 4 cores.